# Robotics jargon question: How to conjugate 'teach'?

Tags: reference-request

As a non-native speaker I have a (maybe trivial, but to me not clear) question concerning the verb 'to teach'. Of course, from school (and online dictionaries) I know the past tense of 'teach' is 'taught' not 'teached'. But in robotics 'to teach' has a special meaning (like: 'to make special ponts/orientations known to the (arm-)robot', e.g. by guiding the robot to those points/orientations.)

Does it make sense to have a different past tense for 'teach' (i.e. 'teached') in this case ? Maybe a reference were it is used/explained ?

(I would say 'No. The past of teach is taught, and that's it.', but some of my colleagues - also not native speakers - have a different opinion.)

Comment: Check http://dict.leo.org/ is your language present there? to teach so. | taught, taught |

Comment: Yes, I've checked leo.org. I've edited the question.

Comment: I know this for `dream`, which allows both `dreamed` or `dreamt`. But not for `teach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have paid online or DVD access to Oxford English Dictionary, you can look up the entry for *teached*.  Here is its entry from OED1 (1919 vintage, available free online):

> Teached ... *Obs.* or *dial.* = TAUGHT.
>   1639 LO. DIGAY, etc. *Lett. conc. Relig.* (1651) 96 By the
>   frequent misapprehension of the teached,..either let slip or supplanted. 1644 G. PLATTES in Hartlib's Legacy (1655)
>   176 The Teachers and the Teached were nothing else but
>   the blind leading of the blind.

That is, OED (which typically is regarded as a definitive reference) in its first release referred to *teached* as obsolete or dialectic, and labels it as meaning *taught*.

*[Garner's Modern American Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=mVcJqKs1isUC&pg=PA798&lpg=PA798&dq=teached+or+taught&source=bl&ots=zuw_rJNhvz&sig=T1nJwq74BT9upWTw9JMDTs7yv6A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UoTbVJijEoG1ogTajoCQCQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=teached%20or%20taught&f=false)* (2009, Oxford University Press) by Bryan Garner in its ***Teach*** > taught > taught entry states

> `*`*Teached* is a form that isn't taught anywhere and is no part of STANDARD ENGLISH. But it sometimes appears –

and offers some examples of it appearing by mistake in American newspaper articles.

The [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teached) entry for *teached* labels it as “nonstandard, colloquial, dialectal” and offers some dialectal examples.

In short, use *taught*, not *teached*.  But note that rather than referring to a robot “replaying a collection of *taught* poses”, more often one refers to it “replaying a collection of *learned* poses”, making the viewpoint that of the taught instead of of the teacher.

Comment: Great research.
Curiously, we have two forms also for the past of _learn_: learned and learnt; this time, both correct.